# Is it more efficient to split a large table into several tables, or stick with one, in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm writing a C# program where I'm looking at ~5300 stock tickers.  I'm storing the data in a MySQL database with the following fields: date, tickername, closingPrice, movingaverage50, movingaverage200, ... and a few others.  Each stock can have up to 15300 different datapoints.  So the total database will be 5300x15300x6 or so different fields.

My question is, is there a more efficient way to store all this data other than one big table?  Would breaking the data up into different tables, say by decade, buy me anything?  Is there some link/website where I should go to get a general feel of what considerations I should look at to design a database to be as fast as possible, or does the MySQL database itself make it efficient?

I'm currently reading in 5500 excel files one at a time to fill my c# objects with data, and that takes around 15minutes... I'm assuming once I get my MySQL going that will be cut way down.

Thanks for any help; this is more of a fishing for a place to get started thinking about database design I guess.

Comment: Look also at partitioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

In general, it is a bad idea to store multiple tables with the same format.  That becomes a maintenance problem and has dire consequences for certain types of queries.  So, one table is preferred.

The total number of rows is 486,540,000.  This is pretty large but not extraordinary.

The question about data layout depends not only on the data but how it is being used.  My guess is that the use of indexes and perhaps partitions would solve your performance problems.

Processing 5,500 Excel files in 15 minutes seems pretty good.  Whether the database will be significantly faster depends on the volume of data between the server and the application.  If you are reading the "Excel" files as CSV text files, then the database may not be a big gain.  If you are reading through Excel, then it might be better.

Note: with a database, you may be able to move processing from C# into the database.  This allows the database to take advantage of parallel processing, which can open other avenues for performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

- One table.
- `PRIMARY KEY(ticker, date)` -- This makes getting historical info about a single ticker efficient because of the clustering.
- `PARTITION BY (TO_DAYS(date))` -- This leads to all the `INSERT` activity being in a single partition.  This partition is of finite size, hence the random accessing to insert 5300 new rows every night scattered around will probably still be in cache.
- Partition by month, or something of approximately that size -- small enough for a partition to be cached, but not so small enough that you have an unwieldy number of partitions.  (It is good to keep a table under 50 partitions.  This 'limitation' may lift with "native partitions" that are coming in 5.7.)
- If you *already* have several months' data in a table, put that in a single, oversized, partition; there is no advantage in splitting it up by month.
- Minimize column sizes.  2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` for `ticker_id`, linked to a normalization table of tickers.  3-byte `DATE`; etc.  Volume can be too big for `INT UNSIGNED`, either use `FLOAT` (with some roundoff error) or some `DECIMAL`.  Prices are tricky -- rounding errors with FLOAT, excessive size with DECIMAL: need at least (9,4) (5 bytes) for US tickers, worse if you go back to the days of fractional pricing (eg, 5-9/16).
- Think through the computation of moving averages; this may be the most intensive activity.